# is Neo4J-spatial already included in heroku?

Tags: heroku, geospatial, neo4j

I have been reading about Neo4J: https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/TestSimplePointLayer.java

but I cant' understand how to use them, in fact I don't even know if this is supported in the beta version of Neo4J in heroku, could someone tell me if this is possible and if so, do you have some code that can guide me on how to add Latitude/Longitude to a node? In REST API if you can, because I'm using .Net so I can't have the complete client library in java

thanks in advance

Comment: Heroku basic plans only include the raw Neo4j instance, without addons ATM. Look at http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2 for a guide on how to roll your own instance at EC2 etc.

Comment: thanks Peter, I'm looking for all the possible alternatives, and now that you mention EC2 I'll check that, I have also read about Neo4J in Windows Azure but I thought having a dedicated instance was too much burden for my tests. Such a pitty.

Comment: yes, I think EC2 is your best option to start with, and mostly used.

Comment: I'm also having the problem, i don't know how to connect to heroku add-on neo4j because it contains username and password, how to use it?